# React if checking whether the object is empty return false instead of true

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In the below class, I am conditionally rendering 2 divs. If the vehicleDetails object does not contain data I am rendering the

```
<p> Vehicle Details Not Availble </p>
```

But, React renders

```
<p> Vehicle Details Availble </p>
```

for about 2 seconds even though the vehicle Details object is empty. And, it goes away and works correctly. This behavior is not acceptable. How can I stop this behavior?

Additionally, the getVehicleDetails() is async function. When I console.log the vehicleDetails, initially it prints two empty objects 3 times. But, My problem is even though I checked whether the object contains data, the checks do not work.

```
class Vehicle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { vechileId = 123 }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { vehicleId } = this.state;
    const { getVehicleDetails } = this.props;
    getVehicleDetails(vehicleId);
  }

  render() {
    const { vehileDetails } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {!(vehileDetails && Object.keys(vehileDetails).length !== 0) ? (
          <p> Vehicle Details Not Availble </p>
        ) : (
          <p> Vehicle Details Availble </p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getVehicleDetails: () =>
    dispatch(getVehicleDetails()),
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { vehileDetails } = state;
  return { vehileDetails };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Vehicle);
```

Comment: can you share console.log of vehileDetails when it is empty?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela It logs as "vehicleDetails : {}"

Comment: @SoulGood Ideally you should have `loading` variable which should be false until you get data from `getVehicleDetails()` And then wrap everything inside loading. If loading is false then display everything otherwise display loading bar.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Actually in this scenario, I want to know why my if  check does not work for the empty object.

Comment: What this method returns `getVehicleDetails()`? An array or object?

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya getVehicleDetails() return an object.

Comment: Then your issue is with this line `return { vehileDetails };` Here, you put an object inside an object. Instead just do `return vehileDetails||{}`;

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya It's the props object. I have destructured the props and got the vehicleDetails using "const { vehileDetails } = this.props".